# Debugging old VC6 DLL

Tags: visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-6

I am trying to debug old DLLs (for which I have the project and source code) used by an APP (which I cannot build anymore). The project was developed using Visual Studio 6, so this is what I am using as well.

What I tried without success:

- Added MsgBox in a routine that I know for sure it is called by the APP (so I can have a pause to attach the debugger to the process)
- Built the Debug version of the DLL
- Deployed the DLL and PDB in the folder where the APP is (overwriting the original DLL)
- Added the path to deployed DLL in Project Settings -> Debug -> Additional DLLs (VS 6)
- Started the APP. The MsgBox popup showed. I attached to the APP process and added breakpoints
- Breakpoints are hit but the "Go To Source" does not reveal the sources

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does VC6 not have a "Find Source" button, or dialog? Also, usually it's possible to use a more recent Visual Studio to debug executables built with older ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with VC6 even when I had the sources for the DLL and the project.   I think you can browse to the sources, if you look at the call stack it should tell you what line of the source to go to.
The other option is to open the VS6.0 IDE on your DLL project which you have sources to, but in the Debugger settings place the name of the APP exe and fire it up with arguments, I think that was the technique I used to use.
I don't use VS6.0 much anymore, and have to fire up a virtual machine to even use it.
Although there is a hack/trick to force install VS6.0 on a modern Win7/WinServer2019 machine.  You have to disable some install components which will hang the install. But it will install and run, I just no longer have media.